# ios scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is not working UICollectionView , but is working for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

i am using a **"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating"** for load more data when user go to last on list data scroller and same page (on this page) i am using UICollectionView and  same think when user go to last page load more data 
but **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating** is not working for UICollectionView please help 
here is my code 
i think **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating** is work for both UICollexction and Tableview but when i try to add one more SCrollerViewDidEndDec this return a error because i already defined in one time

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
        HUD.frame = CGRectMake(95, 330, 140, 150);
        HUD.labelText = @"Load More ...";
        HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Load More ...";
        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;

        [HUD show:YES];

        [self.view addSubview:HUD];

        fromValue =fromValue+4; //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", endvalue];

        [self getdata2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement both `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`

A complete solution involves checking that `willDecelerate` is `NO` and invoking the same logic you have in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` - this delegate method is called if you stopped scrolling without deceleration

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (!decelerate) {
        // preloading logic
    }
}
```